# Excel 2016, Getting all column headers that contain a certain Value

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet with many columns each have a unique header
These columns contain Dates

I need to make a report (Like Pivot table), to get me all the column headers of the specified date

I tried to give an example here, but I can't So I included an example workbook below, also I added a screen shot that describes how the data is built

Screen Shot:

[image]

[Example Workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TbBkIbayLRBoxHBgYxA5t5woeVCB5ihW)

What I need is a report just like pivot table, to enable me for example if I selected the Month April.2019 to give me all column Headers that contain this value

I know that in the original data if I made a new row for each date and just one column for the type I can get the pivot table to work

I am asking if there is any way around this

Thanks in advance

Comment: re: *'I tried to give an example here, but I can't ...'* - please explain this. Showing some level of original effort is expected. This is not a site to get *'What I need'* and *'I am asking if there is any way around this'* is not a specific question unless you simply want someone to respond with **yes**..

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I can't include an example in the question itself,
So I added a screenshot showing what I mean.
is this accepted or I must add the example in the question itself ?

Comment: And why pray tell can you not include sample data or the code that you have worked on so far in your question? People with less rep than you have been doing it for almost 10 years.

Comment: Can you insert the screenshots as pictures and not as link? Some of us find links more dubious and do not trust them

Comment: @Jeeped
It's just that I am using normal excel sheet, No VBA code is included So to describe the situation it would take so many sentences, which could be saved in 1 second if you looked at the screenshot
The situation is let's say I have 1 Column Contains Unique letters (A,B,C, etc...)
from the 2nd to the 10th Column (each have a unique Header)
I have date values in most of the rows
I need to make a report so that if I select for example a date (25.May.2018) 
it tells me that on this day you have the Column Header 3,7,10
I hope It is clear

Comment: @Pierre44
I think I need 10 reputation points to post a photo directly (I am only 8)
I used the site tool to add this image, if you have any other way to post the photo that is more safe and trust-able please tell me

Comment: oh-key-doh-key. Despite the absence of code that might explain things not covered in your narrative, I think I get it now. I'll give this a shot just as soon as I retype your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below will search you Stability Sheet and place all found column headers in Column B of Sheet Report, as long as you enter the date you are searching for in A1 of Report:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Stability")
Dim wsReport As Worksheet: Set wsReport = Sheets("Report")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
icounter = 0
X = Format(wsReport.Cells(1, 1).Value, "dd.mmm.yyyy")
'above enter value to search for in Sheet Report A1
Set valuefound = ws.Range("AG3:BI5000").Find(What:=X, LookIn:=xlValues)
'above look for value X in column B
If Not valuefound Is Nothing Then 'if found then
    foundaddress = valuefound.Address 'save the address of the first instance found
    LastRow = wsReport.Cells(wsReport.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsReport.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(2, valuefound.Column)
    FoundAt = ws.Cells(2, valuefound.Column)
    Do
        Set valuefound = ws.Range("AG3:BI5000").FindNext(valuefound) 'find next value
        LastRow = wsReport.Cells(wsReport.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsReport.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(2, valuefound.Column)
    Loop While Not valuefound Is Nothing And valuefound.Address <> foundaddress
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code,
It is a good point to start from. I was hoping for a VBA free solution but I guess there is none